# HTML page background image is display in node js server

Tags: html, css, node.js

This is my html file. 1st.jpg file is in same folder. But still it's can't load on server. I don't understand what to do. I tried using inline css, embedded css as well external css also.

In debugging they shows Image can't load.

Code:-

```js
//Form hidding Effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#main").hide();
  });
});

//Button hidding Effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#b1").hide();
  });
});

//Sub division hidding Effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("sub").hide();
  });
});

//FadeIn Effect on text
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#display").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});

//FadeOut Effect on text
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#display").fadeOut(8000);
  });
});

//FadeIn effect on Game_Table
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#game_div").fadeIn(13000);
  });
});

function setUsername() {
  var user = {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    // lastname: document.getElementById('lastname').value,
    // address: document.getElementById('address').value,
    gen: document.getElementById('gen').value,
    city: document.getElementById('city').value,
    // emailid: document.getElementById('emailid').value,
    // mobileno: document.getElementById('mobileno').value,
  };

  var data = {
    data: {
      en: "insert",
      data: user
    }
  };
  console.log("here-->", user)
  socket.emit('req', data);
};
```

```css
.name {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Time-new-roman;
}

table {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: #DCB68E;
}


/*button{
       margin-left: 30%;
       padding-left: 5%;
      }*/

td {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 8%;
}

.input_name {
  width: 130px;
}

.input_btn:hover {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#shadow1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px black;
}

.ft_clr {
  color: #3f0a0a;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'TheBlacklist';
  src: url('./TheBlacklist/TheBlacklist.woff');
}

.div1 {
  width: 326px;
  height: 277px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 326px;
  height: 55px;
}

.div3 {
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 600px;
}

.input_btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 175%;
  font-family: TheBlacklist;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px black;
}

.h1_txt {
  color: black;
  font-size: 400%;
  font-family: TheBlacklist;
}

body {
  background-image: url('1st.jpg');
  "

}

#game_table {
  margin-top: 70px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px black;
}

#game_table td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#game_div {
  background-image: url('1st.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>For in Row</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


</head>

<body background="./1st.jpg">
  <div id="main" class="div1">
    <form action="" id="Registration" method="">
      <table cellpadding="1" bgcolor="white" align="left" cellspacing="2" id="shadow1">
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2>
            <center><b><h1 class="ft_clr"><font style="font-family: TheBlacklist">Gamer Registration</font></h1></b></center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Gamer Name</td>
          <td><input type=text name=textnames id="name" size="30" class="input_name"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Gender</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="gen" value="male" size="10" id="gen">Male<input type="radio" name="gen" value="Female" size="10" id="gen">Female</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>City</td>
          <td>
            <select name="City" id="city">
              <option value="-1" selected>Country</option>
              <option value="uk">UK</option>
              <option value="usa">USA</option>
              <option value="india">India</option>
              <option value="russia">Russia</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="sub" class="div2">
    <center><button id="b1" class="input_btn" onclick="setUsername()">Play</button></center>
  </div>

  <div id="display" class="div3" style="display: none">
    <center>
      <h1 class="h1_txt">Connecting to the Server..</h1>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Look for the request for the background image. Look for the response. Are they are you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. It was working if i open html directly but not from nodejs. I couldn't find easy way but i found alternative solution.

- Try full path or
- http links (after uploded images to the web)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"` from 
`body{
            background-image: url('1st.jpg');"
        }`

Comment: In fact, this would fail regardless of using node.

Answer (score 0):

obsolete way

```
<body background="./1st.jpg">
```

try on the CSS

```
 body{
      background-image: url('./1st.jpg');"
   }
```

Verify url direction of image

```
// Folder Up    
"../image.jpg"

// same folder of CSS in this case
"image.jpg"

// Root direction
"/image.jpg"
```

Comment: I tried both way. It's working if i run only HTML page. But when I open that HTML page using node js server at that time background image is not working.